# How can I select all text within matching PHP tags in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

How can I select all the content within matching PHP tags in Sublime Text 3?

I know by pressing the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> inside an HTML `div`, select the entire `div`, and keep pressing until the HTML tag pairs match. But this shortcut doesn't work with PHP tags as shown in the following example:

```
<?php
$x = 5;
$y = 4;
echo $x + $y;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression

```
(?<=<\?php)((.|\n)*?)(?=\?>)
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com/3tp7e)

Comment: Or `(?s)(?<=<\?php).*?(?=\?>)`